# IIS not retain Application State Variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have created a MVC application and tested in my local , it was working as expected, but when I deployed in to an other server in application pool. It is not retaining the Application State Variable value.

So I changed all the Application State variable to Static custom objects and tried.Again I cannot get any values from the static variables used.

As I seen from some blog,I changed the mode from Integrated to Classic, even then I can get the value.

Can any one please help me in getting out from the issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying to a webfarm or are your servers clustered? if so - thats the problem. There is no guarentee you will hit the next server the same one as the one that served the request. The app pool has nothing to do with the behavior here (only in exceptional scenarios) but rather your environment.

Did you create a seperate app pool for this application? if not - its best practice to do so.